# Ajax error: "Syntax error: Unexpected token <"

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using an MVC 5 application and I'm trying to pass data through ajax to my controller, but I get a "Syntax error: Unexpected token <". Not sure why.

Here is my html page with the javascript.

```
@model webby.Models.Calendar



<div id="calendar">
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="padding:20.5% 15%;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Events on @ViewBag.Date</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table>


                        <tr> 
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor( model=> model.events)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.type)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.content)
                            </td>
                        </tr>



                </table>


            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                height: 170,
                selectable: true,
                editable: true,
                defaultView: 'basicWeek',
                dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {

                    $.ajax(
                    {

                        url: '@Url.Action("Calendar","Home")',
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ date: date }),
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert(response);
                        },
                        error: function (request, status, error) {
                            alert(error);
                            alert(status);
                            alert(request.responseText);
                        }
                    });

                    $('#myModal').modal();
                }
            });    

        });

    </script>
```

Here is my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public ActionResult Calendar(string date)
    {



        DateTime objDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

        var content = db.Calendars.Where(x => x.startDate == objDate).Single();


        return PartialView(content);
    }
```

I believe this error is causing the data to not be displayed in my view after being pushed through the post of my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what is being returned by

```
JSON.stringify({ date: date })
```

I am sure you will find the culprit there.